# Include module in rspec

Tags: rspec2

Please forgive my gherkin

```
Given I have a module called Hello
And it has a method called world and a class called World
When I include the module in an RSpec spec 
And I call the method world 
Then it returns "hello world from method"
But when I create a World class
Then I get NameError: uninitialized constant World

module Hello
  def world
    p "hello world from method"
  end
  class World
     def initialize
       p "hello world from class"
     end
  end
end

describe "hello world" do
  include Hello
  it "call method" do
    world
  end

  it "call class" do
    World.new
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the way you've specified your question is confusing (based on the one answerer not understanding it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive my Gherkin, and unless you intended something else (as that's not clear)

```
When I create a Hello::World class  
Then I get an object of kind Hello::World

it "should not catch fire on instantiation" do
  Hello::World.new.should_not be_nil
end
```

Comment: No my point was that I can't call World.new even though I have included Hello in my spec. I would have thought including the module would have made the Hello class available.

Comment: `include` will only add in instance methods defined on the module, whereas `World.new` is calling a method defined on a class in the namespace given by the module. If you really want a helper method for the instantiation, then something like `def new; World.new; end` in the Hello module should work (but confusing, I'd name it "world_creator" or something like that. When it comes to calling things in namespaces, I tend to use the whole namespace anyway, as it cuts down on bugs (or anxiety about causing bugs! :)